# GeoDjango admin map draws point at wrong location

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, geometry, geodjango

I have a model like

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class Letter(models.Model):
    """Letter Model"""

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Letter'
    center = models.PointField(geography=True)
```

and the model has a data as follows:

```
a = models.Letter.objects.get(id='699c49db-1db7-41cf-90a9-a173f9352805')
print(a.center)
SRID=4326;POINT (-74 40.718)
```

Any causes and solution for this?
[image: misat]

Could somebody help me find the cause and solution for this?

Comment: what version of GDAL are you using?